# Change the project to web application

Tags: java, maven

I have created java application that use **Hibernate and Spring Maven** but it does not have any web component. this project create jar file that used in another web project.
At now I want to convert the project that create jar file to j2ee **web** application. 
What steps should I do change it?

project

```
---src
 |
  main___
  |      |java
  |
   -_____resources
  |           |
  |           applicationContext.xml
  |           |
  |            dataSource.xml
  |
  |
  ||
   test
```

Comment: Google will help you.... Try it once before you post it.

Comment: Before I sent it I google this question but i cannot find answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [maven standard directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). For web app sources you will need a `src/main/webapp` directory.

If you want to use spring mvc, refer to [spring mvc documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) and [example showcase](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase).

Comment: what file is placed in webapp?

Comment: `WEB-INF` directory and under it `web.xml` file.